# I cannot get loop to work and when I press the button to exit my switch it does not work

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

Now I have the while loop working but now it is looping the answer of the first operation instead of asking to input another number for more operations and when I press x to exit it does not exit. I was just wondering where to put the line of code to ask to input for another set of numbers. Then for the the input of Y or X yes to continue and x to exit where I could put the line of code for that. I just need to know where that's all thanks :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char op, x, y;





double scanNumber() {
    double d;

    cin >> d;

    return d;
}

bool readOperator(string s, char &operation) {
    char c;
    cout << "\nEnter Operator: ";
    cin >> c;
    if (s.find(c) != -1) {
        operation = c;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

double add(double d1, double d2) {
    return d1 + d2;
}

double sub(double d1, double d2) {
    return d1 - d2;
}

double mul(double d1, double d2) {
    return d1*d2;
}


double division(double d1, double d2) {
    return d1 / d2;
}
int main()

{

    double d1, d2;


    cout << "Enter 1st Number: ";
    d1 = scanNumber();

    cout << "Enter 2nd Number: ";
    d2 = scanNumber();

    char operation;
    while (!readOperator("+-*/", operation)) {
        cout << "Invalid Operator Please Pick Another One" << endl;


    }

    bool valid;
    double result;



    do{
        switch (operation)
        {

        case '+':
            result = add(d1, d2);
            break;
        case '-':
            result = sub(d1, d2);
            break;
        case '*':
            result = mul(d1, d2);
            break;
        case '/':
            if (d2 == 0) {
                cout << "For division, 2nd operator can't be 0." << endl;

            }
            else {
                result = division(d1, d2);
            }
            break;
        case 'c':
            cout << "Clearing the Calculator " << endl;
            valid = false;
            break;
        case 'x':
            exit(0);
        default:
            cout << "invalid input";

        }

    cout << "\nResult: " << result << endl;
    cout << "\nDo another?(Enter 'y'for yes or 'x' to exit )  ";

    cin >> y, x;
}while (op != 'x');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either use `getline()` to read your inputs, or use `cin.ignore()` to skip over the newline that's left in the input stream after reading `operation`.

Comment: Any code following a `return` statement will not be executed.  Execution will leave the function before the next statement is executed.

Comment: There's nothing that checks whether `ch` is `y` or `x`.

Comment: You should just put a `while (true)` loop around the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

You have no logic to repeat the loop again after you have made a calculation. So you need a `do` to pair with the lone `while (op != 'x');` you have left at the end.

This is how you could do it:

```
int main() {

    double d1, d2;

    do {  //main loop now starts here
        cout << "Enter 1st Number: ";
        d1 = scanNumber();
        cout << "Enter 2nd Number: ";
        d2 = scanNumber();

        char operation;

        //since you have a switch on the c and x operator they need to be taken into 
        //consideration in this while loop
        while (!readOperator("+-*/cCxX", operation)) {
            cout << "Invalid Operator Please Pick Another One" << endl;
        }

        bool valid;
        double result;

        switch (operation) {
        case '+': result = add(d1, d2); break;
        case '-': result = sub(d1, d2); break;
        case '*': result = mul(d1, d2); break;
        case '/':
            if (d2 == 0) {
                cout << "For division, 2nd operator can't be 0." << endl;
            }
            else {
                result = division(d1, d2);
            }
            break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            cout << "Clearing the Calculator " << endl;
            valid = false;
            break;
        case 'x':
        case 'X': return 0;
        default: cout << "invalid input";
        }

        //You need to use the valid as well to know if you show the result
        if (valid) cout << "\nResult: " << result << endl;
        cout << "\nDo another(Enter 'y'for yes or 'x' to exit ) ? ";
        cin >> ch;

    } while (ch != 'x'); //now the } ends here and the condition uses ch

    return 0; //return is now after the while
}
```

Sample run with the proposed input:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help @Isac but now i've ran into another situation where after I do 2 math operations the third operator i put in and press enter. It gives me invalid operator and keeps printing out the lines for invalid operator also when I press c to clear it also gives me an invalid operator and It should be clearing the calculator instead. Thank you guys for everything so far!

Comment: @Jerry i can't seem to recreate that error. Can you tell me exactly what input you entered and its exact order?

Comment: Yes thank you! I did 3+3 = 6 for the first operation. 2*4 = 8 for the second operation. The third time is when after inputting the numbers I put in the operator and that's when it starts printing out invalid operator please pick another one nonstop.

Comment: @Jerry Take a look at the edit regarding the validation `while` and the result print

Comment: hmm I had a friend run it as and apparently i'm the only one having problems with math operations after the second time. Thank you for everything @Isac! The only problem I have left is for my switch when I press c to clear the calculator it gives an invalid operator.

Comment: @Jerry Have you changed the validation `while` to account for it ? This one `while (!readOperator("+-*/cCxX", operation)) {`. Note how it has the `cC` as well

Comment: yes @Isac everything is finished now thank you for all your help

Comment: @Jerry No problem. Best of luck.